# How to plot a different candlestick graph on the same figure?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot candlestick graphs and save each graph I plot. For speed, I want to do this on the same figure.
So far, I can save the first image but the rest are blank.

I've tried using:

```
pltclf()
plt.cla()
fig.clear()
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc
from itertools import count
colNames = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']  
allData = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0, names=colNames, usecols=colNames,
                      parse_dates={'Datetime': ['Date', 'Time']},
                      infer_datetime_format=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for n in count(0, 10):
    subset = allData[n:n+10]
    plt.axis('off')
    try:
        candlestick2_ohlc(ax, subset['Open'], subset['High'], subset['Low'],
                          subset['Close'], width=0.6, colorup='g',
                          colordown='r', alpha=1)
    except ValueError:
        print("Graphing done.")
        break
    fig.savefig("{}.png".format(str(n)))
    plt.show()
    fig.clf()
```

CSV File used (file.csv):

```
Date,Time,OpenBid,HighBid,LowBid,CloseBid
01/02/2009,09:31:00,1212.23,1212.29,1211.77,1211.77
01/02/2009,09:32:00,1211.53,1212.18,1211.29,1211.29
01/02/2009,09:33:00,1209.11,1209.91,1209.11,1209.91
01/02/2009,09:34:00,1210.3,1211.29,1210.3,1211.28
01/02/2009,09:35:00,1213.51,1214.51,1213.11,1213.11
01/02/2009,09:36:00,1212.79,1212.79,1212.56,1212.71
01/02/2009,09:37:00,1213.65,1214.33,1213.65,1213.75
01/02/2009,09:38:00,1213.39,1213.76,1213.39,1213.76
01/02/2009,09:39:00,1211.32,1213.17,1211.32,1213.17
01/02/2009,09:40:00,1213.92,1215.87,1213.92,1215.87
01/02/2009,09:41:00,1215.61,1216.1,1215.4,1216.1
01/02/2009,09:42:00,1215.74,1215.75,1214.07,1214.07
01/02/2009,09:43:00,1214.36,1214.88,1213.87,1214.88
01/02/2009,09:44:00,1215,1215,1213.35,1214.03
01/02/2009,09:45:00,1214.04,1214.44,1214.04,1214.12
01/02/2009,09:46:00,1214.16,1214.56,1214.16,1214.56
01/02/2009,09:47:00,1214.68,1214.93,1214.62,1214.68
01/02/2009,09:48:00,1215.59,1216.11,1215.59,1216.11
01/02/2009,09:49:00,1216.37,1216.37,1215.54,1215.61
01/02/2009,09:50:00,1215.29,1215.29,1214.28,1214.28
01/02/2009,09:51:00,1213.82,1213.82,1212.87,1212.99
01/02/2009,09:52:00,1212.25,1212.44,1212.21,1212.25
01/02/2009,09:53:00,1212.05,1212.05,1210.24,1210.24
01/02/2009,09:54:00,1210.05,1210.21,1209.27,1210.21
01/02/2009,09:55:00,1209.83,1210.68,1209.83,1209.99
01/02/2009,09:56:00,1209.97,1210.91,1209.97,1210.91
01/02/2009,09:57:00,1211.45,1212.62,1211.38,1212.17
01/02/2009,09:58:00,1212.42,1212.42,1212.26,1212.41
01/02/2009,09:59:00,1212.39,1212.39,1212.33,1212.33
01/02/2009,10:00:00,1212.28,1212.28,1211.26,1212.14
01/02/2009,10:01:00,1212.99,1214.66,1212.99,1214.19
01/02/2009,10:02:00,1213.91,1213.91,1213.16,1213.55
01/02/2009,10:03:00,1213.53,1213.53,1213.41,1213.46
01/02/2009,10:04:00,1212.67,1213.21,1212.54,1213.21
01/02/2009,10:05:00,1213.52,1213.81,1213.52,1213.52
01/02/2009,10:06:00,1213.34,1213.4,1213.29,1213.29
01/02/2009,10:07:00,1213.46,1213.6,1213.14,1213.14
01/02/2009,10:08:00,1213.37,1213.81,1213.37,1213.8
01/02/2009,10:09:00,1213.57,1214.5,1213.57,1214.45
01/02/2009,10:10:00,1214.93,1215.03,1214.62,1214.62
```

I think the issue is to do with candlestick2_ohlc and that it plots to 'ax', but I don't know how to resolve my issue.

Comment: I suppose you want to replace `fig.clf()` by `ax.clear()`, i.e. clearing the axes, not the figure.

Comment: Strangely, this maintains the problem of graphs appearing blank when .show() (excluding the first graph). But, the graphs are now saved correctly, except all with their axis included (excluding the first graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc
from itertools import count
colNames = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']  
allData = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), header=0, names=colNames, usecols=colNames,
                      parse_dates={'Datetime': ['Date', 'Time']},
                      infer_datetime_format=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for n in count(0, 10):
    subset = allData[n:n+10]
    plt.axis('off')
    if len(subset)>0:
        candlestick2_ohlc(ax, subset['Open'], subset['High'], subset['Low'],
                          subset['Close'], width=0.6, colorup='g',
                          colordown='r', alpha=1)
        fig.savefig("{}.png".format(str(n)))
        ax.clear()
    else:
        break
```